# Repeated iterations in foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, multicore, doparallel

I am using the `foreach(i = 2:366)` function in `R` with `doParallel()` as my back-end. In the past I haven't had any issues but now I'm attempting to run 365 *complex* iterations in parallel and some are being repeated. As the `foreach()` output `rbinds` the results, I'm expecting an array of length 365 yet I get one of length 384. My loop also prints `i` as part of the array but I occasionally get duplicates (i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6). Any insight into why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: post the most relevant sections of your code in whole

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I have since removed the foreach() function and returned to serial computation. I will try to recreate the foreach loop in the coming days.